# NFS daemon not starting up with error message "Kernel does not have pseudo root support"

Tags: linux, debian, nfs

My nfs daemon is not starting up anymore. I see the following entries in the syslog:

```
Sep 26 18:21:10 VOXWEBPRODDHNCGN001 mountd[3401]: Kernel does not have pseudo root support.
Sep 26 18:21:10 VOXWEBPRODDHNCGN001 mountd[3401]: NFS v4 mounts will be disabled unless fsid=0
Sep 26 18:21:10 VOXWEBPRODDHNCGN001 mountd[3401]: is specfied in /etc/exports file.
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have NFS server support built into your kernel. Check the output of the following command:

```
grep NFSD /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

You need `CONFIG_NFSD=m` or `CONFIG_NFSD=y`.